# How to parallelize a for loop inside a method with pointers to objects

Tags: performance, class, for-loop, pointers, openmp

I am trying to parallelize a for loop inside a class using pointers to objects.
However, the performance of the loop is always 3.7 seconds regardless of the number of threads used.

Here is the part of the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <omp.h>

#include "data.hpp"
#include "model.hpp"
#include "sub.hpp"

void Data::apply(Data* data, Model* model, Sub* sub, unsigned i)
{
    omp_set_num_threads(omp_get_max_threads()); // max threads is 8

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int j = 0; j < model->n_max; ++j) //model->n_max is 20 000 000
    {
        sub->cur[j] = sub->old[i * model->n_old + j] * sub->i + sub->predict[j];
    }
}
```

Can you explain me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you use compilation flags enabling OpenMP? How your program is compiled?

Comment: yes I use target_link_libraries(mylibs -lstdc++fs -fopenmp) and add_library(mylibs ${MYLIBS_SRC}) in the CMakeLists file. And for the release version I use set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O3 -DNDEBUG -fopenmp" CACHE STRING "" FORCE )

Comment: This is not enouth for OpenMP, you need to add it to the compiler flags too. This solution is not portable. You can try the [modern CMake solution](https://cliutils.gitlab.io/modern-cmake/chapters/packages/OpenMP.html). Besides this, check the generated command calling the compiler are correct (so `-fopenmp` must be present for both the compilation of the object files and the link of the final binary).

Comment: OK thank you for the input. I updated my cmake files. I just tried a simple loop with a math expression and it works, but when I run the loop shown above it still doesn't work. I am not sure if I create any race condition or cache issues.

Comment: I guess this is due to the hardware but I am not sure. It is very hard to tell without a *minimal complete reproducible code* and some hardware information (processor & memory).

Comment: `omp_set_num_threads(omp_get_max_threads()); // max threads is 8` is a waste of time, since that is the default anyway.